# Laravel storage link doesnt link with public

Tags: laravel

Try to upload my files to storage, and link it with my public folder.

I used

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Then, I upload photos like below;

```
        $filename = uniqid().".".$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filePath = 'uploads/announcement';
        Storage::disk('public')->putFileAs($filePath, $file, $filename, ['visibility' => 'public']);
        $announcement->photo = $filename ?? $announcement->filename;
```

But my /public/storage folder is empty, when I upload files.
Whats wrong with it?

My filesystem.php is below;

```
    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path(),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the way i do it (i n livewire but the storePubliclyAs Is not livewire)

```
if($this->image != null){
            $imageName = time().'.'.$this->image->extension(); 
            $company->image= $imageName;       
            // on upload l image dans le folder 
            $this->image->storePubliclyAs('companylogos',$imageName);
        }
```

companylogos is the name of the folder in (storage/app)

i had same problem as you first ! you need to make sure your folder is linked , for that you need to see a little logo on the folder like a link logo meaning that the two folders are sync (linked) , the error is to create both files and try to link them , no you have to create only the storage/app/companylogos folder first and then use artisan to link php artisan storage:link

of course you need to have prepared your file in config filesystems, this is how i did it

```
'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),


        
        public_path('profilecv') => storage_path('app/profilecv'),


        public_path('companylogos') => storage_path('app/companylogos'),

        


    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change file system

filesystem.php is below;

```
 'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```